# the switching timing between high-bandwidth mode and low-bandwidth mode in CompactBlockReray

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip, bandwidth, compact-blocks

If the Compact Block transmission node is bandwidth-limited, there is a statement in bip152 implemention Note that an 'inv/headers' is sent. Are there specific thresholds or settings for this in the Bitcoin Core implementation, and could you please indicate where in the implementation this is located?"